# IBM Worklight Server 6.1 - Adapter to Backend - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I'm working with Worklight 6.0.1. I'm having trouble with certificate verification. Can I remove the certificate checking in Adapters for a PoC project somehow?

I can’t install the correct certificate quickly on the Worklight server. This answer does not provide the right answer: [Disabling certificate hostname verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184349/disabling-certificate-hostname-verification)

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project POD]html/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project POD]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "method": "get",
         "path": "mobile",
         "returnedContentType": "html"
      }
   ]
}

Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <xxx> != <xxx> OR <xxx>
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project POD]javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <xxx> != <xxx> OR <xxx>java.lang.RuntimeException: Http request failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <xxx> != <xxx> OR <xxx>
       at com.worklight.adapters.http.HTTPConnectionManager.execute(HTTPConnectionManager.java:241)
       at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.doExecute(HttpClientContext.java:176)
       at com.worklight.adapters.http.HttpClientContext.execute(HttpClientContext.java:160)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tweak your `hosts` file and make the certificate name point to the machine you're trying to use (and use these URLs).

Comment: Thank you for that idea. I will look into that. I always thought that there is some config option on a Java server that allows to disable such a SSL test for development/test purposes?

Comment: "I always thought that there is some config option on a Java server that allows to disable such a SSL test ..." - its not the server. Its the client that performs the hostname verification.

Comment: well... yes. in this case the client is a server ... we are talking about a WL Server (basically a Servlet-based application on a J2EE server) trying to call some other SSL secured Backend server... on the WL server we would need to deactivate the SSL check...

Comment: Try check my answer here.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035045/ibm-worklight-6-1-runtime-http-request-failed-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifie/21040308#21040308][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035045/ibm-worklight-6-1-runtime-http-request-failed-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifie/21040308#21040308

Comment: If the server you are trying to reach is using a self-signed certificate (and @Bruno's suggestion doesn't help) you should follow the [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc%2Fadmin%2Ft_configuring_SSL_WL_adapters_backend_servers_certificates.html](following guide)

Answer (score 0):

My understand is that you are using WL.Server.invokeHttp in your adapter to call a back-end https service right ?

There is no out-of-the-box option to remove certificate validation from those calls. If you specify https protocol in the adapter configuration then there must be a valid https configuration to be used.

One workaround would be to implement your own https call using java in the worklight server and call it from the adapter. But that way you will be skipping one of the values of the worklight http adapter and maybe it will consume more of your time to do a POC.